# Snowflake Connector for Python Issue

Tags: python, certificate, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connector

I installed snowflake-connector-python and ran my code. The code ran fine with federated authentication.

I am trying to run code again and getting an error. I received the same error earlier in Anaconda and then had to uninstall and reinstall anaconda again, that did not help. I ended up switching to python + pycharm. Same error and same behavior. The code does not run. I am connected to VPN, I disconnected from VPN, put my laptop to sleep, open the laptop and reconnected to VPN.

From description it is some sort of certificate issue. My certificate or IP is changing causing the code to fail.

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x000022c4 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 632 in dump
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 1723 in dump
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 3649 in _set_contents
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 3421 in contents
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 629 in dump
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 4110 in dump
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 3649 in _set_contents
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 3421 in contents
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 629 in dump
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 4110 in dump
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 3649 in _set_contents
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 3421 in contents
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 629 in dump
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 4110 in dump
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 4435 in _set_contents
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 4191 in contents
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 4172 in __init__
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_asn1crypto.py", line 121 in create_ocsp_request
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1153 in _check_ocsp_response_cache_server
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1134 in _validate_certificates_sequential
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 953 in _validate
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 948 in validate
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ssl_wrap_socket.py", line 401 in ssl_wrap_socket_with_ocsp
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 361 in connect
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976 in _validate_conn
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381 in _make_request
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670 in urlopen
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439 in send
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643 in send
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 237 in resolve_redirects
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 665 in <listcomp>
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 665 in send
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530 in request
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 543 in get
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 279 in _download_ocsp_response_cache
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 243 in download_cache_from_server
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1161 in _check_ocsp_response_cache_server
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1134 in _validate_certificates_sequential
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 953 in _validate
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 948 in validate
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ssl_wrap_socket.py", line 401 in ssl_wrap_socket_with_ocsp
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 361 in connect
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976 in _validate_conn
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381 in _make_request
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670 in urlopen
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439 in send
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643 in send
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 237 in resolve_redirects
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 665 in <listcomp>
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 665 in send
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530 in request
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 543 in get
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 279 in _download_ocsp_response_cache
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 243 in download_cache_from_server
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1161 in _check_ocsp_response_cache_server
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1134 in _validate_certificates_sequential
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 953 in _validate
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 948 in validate
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ssl_wrap_socket.py", line 401 in ssl_wrap_socket_with_ocsp
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 361 in connect
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976 in _validate_conn
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381 in _make_request
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670 in urlopen
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439 in send
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643 in send
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 237 in resolve_redirects
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 665 in <listcomp>
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 665 in send
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530 in request
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1335 in _fetch_ocsp_response
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1068 in validate_by_direct_connection
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1139 in _validate_certificates_sequential
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 953 in _validate
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 948 in validate
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ssl_wrap_socket.py", line 401 in ssl_wrap_socket_with_ocsp
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 361 in connect
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976 in _validate_conn
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381 in _make_request
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670 in urlopen
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439 in send
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643 in send
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 237 in resolve_redirects
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 665 in <listcomp>
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 665 in send
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530 in request
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 543 in get
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 279 in _download_ocsp_response_cache
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 243 in download_cache_from_server
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1161 in _check_ocsp_response_cache_server
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1134 in _validate_certificates_sequential
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 953 in _validate
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ocsp_snowflake.py", line 948 in validate
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\ssl_wrap_socket.py", line 401 in ssl_wrap_socket_with_ocsp
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 361 in connect
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976 in _validate_conn
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381 in _make_request
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670 in urlopen
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439 in send
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643 in send
  File "C:\Users\SMudalgi\PycharmProjects\test.py\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 237 in resolve_redirects
  ...

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I just ran into this exact same issue today. The problem was that our environment DNS was not properly set up for our Snowflake AWS VPC endpoints, per their documentation (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-privatelink.html). Without those DNS entries, it was resolving but it gave errors because (I think) there was a region mismatch between where I wanted to go and where I ended up going, so certificate validation failed. It shouldn't be trying over and over to overflow condition, but I think the root cause is environmental. Perhaps you can test by using a hosts file with the OCSP/Snowflake servers set to your endpoint IP.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with snowflake connector. The issue was with the OCSP response.
With privatelink the DNS needs to be configured correctly to get the certificate validated.

I was able to resolve this using "insecure_mode=True" option in the connect call.